# Pandas: Finding values ​of type datetime.time in a column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to find values ​​like `datetime.time` in column `time`:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> import datetime
>>> df = pandas.read_excel('Doc.xlsx')
```

This is how it looks:

```
>>> df['time']
0         21:34:00
```

I looked at the type:

```
>>> for i in df['time']: type(i)
...
>>> <class 'datetime.time'>
```

I tried using a mask but it doesn't work:

```
>>> df.loc[df['time'] == type(datetime.time)]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [time]
Index: []
```

What method can I use to search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['time'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, datetime.time))]
```